# Implicit parameters at the same scope in other files

Tags: scala, implicit, implicit-parameters

Reviewing implicit parameters (and conversions) precedence rules at http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html I found the following priority list:

> 1. First look in current scope
> 2. Implicits defined in current scope
> 3. Explicit imports
> 4. wildcard imports
> 5. <del>Same scope in other files</del>
> 6. ...

I wonder why *Same scope in other files* is crossed out. Is it a pending to implement feature? Has it been removed for some reason? My so far experience shows that the feature isn't available but I'd like to know why is it listed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look below, you can see:

> Same Scope in Other Files
>   Edit: It seems this does not have a different precedence. If you have some example that demonstrates a precedence distinction, please make a comment. Otherwise, don’t rely on this one.
>   This is like the first example, but assuming the implicit definition is in a different file than its usage. See also how package objects might be used in to bring in implicits.

Comment: It might be due my limited English skills but I don't find that comment conclusive: *...Otherwise, don’t rely on this one...* Could you provide more detail? As far as I understand, there is some uncertainty around the feature but I may be wrong.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo It was always crossed out. That content was originally posted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5598107/2292812).

Comment: @m-z Thanks, Do you have any clue on the future availability of the feature?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo No, I think it was just there and crossed out in the SO post.